# laravel insert data in multiple rows and in one loop from API get

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, api

I have data getting from API looks like this:

[image]

How do I can insert data to my database in my controller laravel. Can anyone help me?

Comment: put your response code here not just image. and just loop throug main array and you can access sub object and insert it to DB

Comment: In case relation you can use ‘createMany’ or if you are saving directly you need to use ‘insert’ will create many rows at once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image from the question, you can try some thing like this in your controller

```
public function insertData (Request $request) {
     foreach($request->detailedHistory as $data) 
      {
        $row = new YourModel();
        $row ->column_name1 = $data['DetailedHistoryItem']['date'];
        $row ->column_name2 = $data['DetailedHistoryItem']['source'];
        // and so on for your all columns 
        $row->save();   //at last save into db
      }

}
```

it's all about array manipulation. please have a look at [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks @techguru,, your advice can i used for looping but in my database still null,, please help me

Comment: can you try `dd($request->all());`  in your controller and observe the data ? and may be update the question with your data in controller.